# Unescape a string inside a string

Tags: python, string, http

I am working with `urllib2`, and trying to extract the headers in a printable form from a `Response` object.

Presently I am printing `str(response.info())`, however what is printed, is itself a Python string (at least to my understanding).

```
(Pdb) p str(response.info())
'Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2010 03:12:26 GMT\r\nServer: Apache\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nContent-Length: 9045\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n'
```

I need to turn that string into an "actual" string, such as by evaluation or something similar. The best theoretical solution I've found is to use:

```
s = str(response.info())
print s.decode("string_escape")
```

But this does not work. Further adding to the confusion is how to handle the quotes within the string, calling `eval(s)` and `str(s)` do not work either.

Is there some better way to extract the raw headers in the response without quoting, or a method to decode the string `s` as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str(info())` *does* give a normal string:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://tejp.de')
>>> print str(f.info())
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "-807357257"
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Jul 2009 10:05:34 GMT
Content-Length: 285
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2010 03:24:10 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.19
```

It's only the debugger's `p` command which prints the string in escaped form.

Comment: Good observation; however, this doesn't answer the question *how to unescape a string*.

Comment: @Beau: This was meant to help the OP to do what he really wanted to do, as stated in the first line of his post. Answering the question from the title literally wouldn't have helped him at all. If you are searching for an answer to that, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python) might help.

Answer (score 0):

`response.info()` returns a `httplib.HTTPMessage`, which behaves like a mapping:

```
info = response.info()
for k, v in info.items():
  print '%s: %s' % (k, v)
```

So in short, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From pdb, this should work:

```
print str(response.info())
```

Not sure if that answers your question, though.

Comment: yeah, it returns a python escape string, and prints that quotes and all. nto what i'm after

Comment: It doesn't on my machine. `p` prints the Python-syntax string, whereas `print` yields multi-line output with no visible escapes.

Comment: p is a debugger command. print isn't a debugger command, so is executed as a python statement

Comment: +1: You were right but didn't connect debugger behaviour to my problem.