# Using regex to write backslash character to file

Tags: python, regex

So lets say I receive a string of python code that looks as follows:

```
"def fib(num):\\n\\t#insert code here\\n\\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\\n\\tfor n in numbers:\\n\\t    print(n + \\"\\\\n\\")"
```

I want to rewrite this string so that every time there is two backslashes, they get replaced by one backslash.

I have tried using `code = re.sub(r'(\\)+', "\\", code)` but it gives me an error because the regex pattern ends with a backslash which is [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427174/python-re-bogus-escape-error).

If I try to write `code = re.sub(r'(\\)+', r'\\', code)`, however, it writes the backslash twice instead of once and I can't write `r'\'` because python won't allow it. How would I go about doing this?

### Edits with more info:

I'm using sys.stderr.write(repr(code) + '\n') to find the representation of the strings

Using the above string as the input, I get the following results:

#### Method One

```
code = re.sub(r'(\\\\)+', r"\\", code)
```

Yields: `'def fib(num):\\n\\t#insert code here\\n\\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\\n\\tfor n in numbers:\\n\\t    print(n + \\"\\n\\")'`

And writes to file: `\n\t#insert code here\n\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\n\tfor n in numbers:\n\t    print(n + \"\n\")`

#### Method Two

```
code = code.replace(r'\\', '\\')
```

Yields: `'def fib(num):\\n\\t#insert code here\\n\\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\\n\\tfor n in numbers:\\n\\t    print(n + \\"\\n\\")'`

And writes to file: `\n\t#insert code here\n\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\n\tfor n in numbers:\n\t    print(n + \"\n\")`

#### Method Three

```
code = re.sub(r'(\\)+', "\\", code)
```

Yields Error: `sre_constants.error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0`

#### Method Four

```
code = re.sub(r'(\\)+', r'\\', code)
```

Yields: `'def fib(num):\\n\\t#insert code here\\n\\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\\n\\tfor n in numbers:\\n\\t    print(n + \\"\\n\\")'`

And writes to file: `\n\t#insert code here\n\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\n\tfor n in numbers:\n\t    print(n + \"\n\")`

Comment: `r'\\'` is correct, there is no issue in the question, closing as typo.

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" because the backslash is escaping the rawstring quote

Comment: @usr2564301 No, there is only 1 literal backslash.OP sees the console output.

Comment: Matt, we need to know for sure whether that string that *looks* like what you show *is* the actual string. Be careful not to mix what Python shows with what the string actually contains.

Comment: @usr2564301 I used sys.stderr.write(repr(code) + '\n') to find the above string

Comment: And what appears if you use `print (code)`?

Comment: As suspected, you don't have two backslashes in a row anywhere in your string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python

Comment: @JoshLee I apologize for not posing the question correctly, I think I was a bit confused with when a backslash is considered "in the string" or not. The link to the other SO question was a big help and allowed me to solve the problem. I should've known python had a built-in way of dealing with this. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Makes sense, there's a surprising disconnect between "The computer showed this to me" and what's actually in the string, and there's specialized knowledge in asking the right question. Fortunately, the right question has already been asked and answered well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `re` as it (apparently!) has all kinds of problems with backslashes. You can use the standard [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function:

```
c = code.replace(r'\\','\\')
```

– note the `r` before the first string but *not* before the second string.

This replaces the single occurrence of `\\` in your original string (there are 12 backslashes in there, but only one pair):

```
code = 'def fib(num):\\n\\t#insert code here\\n\\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\\n\\tfor n in numbers:\\n\\t    print(n + \\"\\\\n\\")'
c = code.replace(r'\\','\\')
print (c)
```

with the result

```
def fib(num):\n\t#insert code here\n\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\n\tfor n in numbers:\n\t    print(n + \"\n\")
```

Other *representations* of this result may still *show* double backslashes, but that's just what Python does:

```
>> c
'def fib(num):\\n\\t#insert code here\\n\\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\\n\\tfor n in numbers:\\n\\t    print(n + \\"\\n\\")'
>>> sys.stderr.write(repr(c)+'\n')
'def fib(num):\\n\\t#insert code here\\n\\tnumbers = [1, 2, 3]\\n\\tfor n in numbers:\\n\\t    print(n + \\"\\n\\")'
```