# Python: '\\x41' to '\x41'

Tags: python, string

How can I convert a string like `'\\x41'` to an escaped string like `'\x41'`, using Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> '\\x41'.decode('string_escape')
'A'
```

Gory details [here](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but I'll try to give you some solutions.

1. If you gonna print pure '\x41', you could just

> `print r'\x41'`

1. And if what you want is to print the 'A' out, pls do:

> `print u'\x41'`