# Is there a Python module to parse line break notation in a raw string?

Tags: python, string, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)

If I get this string, for example from a web form:

```
'\n test'
```

The `'\n'` notation won't be interpreted as a line break. How an I parse this string so it becomes a line break?

Of course I can use `replace`, `split`, `re`, etc, to do it manually.

But maybe there is a module for that, since I don't want to be forced to deal with all the `\something` notations manually.

I tried to turn it into bytes then use `str` as a construtor but that doesn't work:

```
>>> str(io.BytesIO(ur'\n'.encode('utf-8')).read())
'\\n'
```

Comment: Are you sure it won't be interpreted as a line break? Do you mean repr(thestring) is '\n test' or "'\n test'"?

Comment: It can't be interpreted as a line break. Line breaks are only interpreted in a string litteral, in the source code. This input comes from the web, if you want to have a code equivalent, you need to write a litteral with the 'r' prefix.

Comment: What do you mean by isn't interpreted as a line break? Are you maybe getting `'\\n'` instead?

Comment: I can not delete it because it has answers. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use .decode('string_escape')

```
>>> print "foo\\nbar\\n\\tbaz"
foo\nbar\n\tbaz
>>> print "foo\\nbar\\n\\tbaz".decode('string_escape')
foo
bar
        baz
```

As I'm typing in code, the above have to escape the \ to make the string contain the 2 characters \n

Edit: actually this is a duplicate of [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)