# python converttion from u'\\u795d\\u798f' to u'\u795d\u798f'

Tags: python, unicode

How to convert from u'\\u795d\\u798f' to u'\u795d\u798f'?

I'm quite confused....

`u'\u795d\u798f'` is `祝福` in Chinese.
Thanks~

**UPDATE:**
I'm sorry, I didn't know how to express it at the beginning. Now, my problem is :I got `u'\\u795d\\u798f'` and I want it to be `u'\u795d\u798f'`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Are you trying to convert something to itself? use `=` and you will get it.

Comment: There are multiple potential formats with `\u` escapes in and each has slightly different rules. If it's a JSON string you should be using a JSON decoder instead of trying to convert the string by hand. How are other escaped characters handled in there? ie do you have `\n` or `\\n`?

Comment: I just passed a string into whoosh.qparser.QueryParser and parse it, and then I got a Query instance conisits of Terms, and I tried to print them out in the form `term[1]`, but failed. That's the problem~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your title (but not the question text) it looks like the problem is that the backslashes in the strings are escaped (i.e., you have `\\u795d` and you want `\u795d`).  There are several questions on this issue (like [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)).

In python 2, you can do:

```
>>> u'\\u795d\\u798f'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u795d\u798f'
```

Applying the `print` statement to this should print the Chinese characters.

The python 3 equivalent is:

```
>>> bytes('\\u795d\\u798f','utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
'祝福'
```