# Converting \x escaped string to UTF-8

Tags: python, unicode

How can convert a string that looks like `'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'` to something readable?

Comment: Note that this is **not** a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/; the input represents UTF-8 bytes which must be re-interpreted as UTF-8 *after* the backslash escape sequences have been unescaped.

Answer (score 21):

### In python 2.7

```
>>> print '\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
привет

>>> print '\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'.decode('string-escape')
привет
>>> print r'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'.decode('string-escape')
привет
```

### In python 3.x

```
>>> br'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'привет'
```

Comment: >>> print '\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0'
жопа

Comment: i suggest that @synapse has r'\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0', i.e. string with slashes.

Comment: @eri, I used '\\' instead of raw string intentionally because this question is not python-only question.

Comment: @falsetru btw, this is rather rude word in Russian :)

Comment: @alecxe, Oops, I will change the code, soon.

Comment: finally find the solutation!!  Where do the python doc specify this situation.

Answer (score 0):

For file reading you may use this instead of `open()`:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('filename','r','string-escape') as f:
    data=f.read()
```

`data` will be reencoded while `f` reading.