# Convert "\x" escaped string into readable string in python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Is there a way to convert a `\x` escaped string like `"\\xe8\\xaa\\x9e\\xe8\\xa8\\x80"` into readable form: `"語言"`?

```
>>> a = "\\xe8\\xaa\\x9e\\xe8\\xa8\\x80"
>>> print(a)
\xe8\xaa\x9e\xe8\xa8\x80
```

I am aware that there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119537/converting-x-escaped-string-to-utf-8), but it seems the solution is only for latin characters.  How can I convert this form of string into readable CJK characters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Decode it first using ['unicode-escape'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings), then as 'utf8':

```
a = "\\xe8\\xaa\\x9e\\xe8\\xa8\\x80"
    
decoded = a.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
print(decoded)

# 語言
```

Note that since we can only decode bytes objects, we need to transparently encode it in between, using 'latin1'.

Comment: I am curious why we need to encode it using latin1, it seems it won't work if I encode it with utf-8: `a.encode('utf8').decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf8').decode('utf8')`

Comment: Because you have a 1 to 1 correspondence between bytes and characters in latin1, while some characters are represented by up to 4 bytes when encoded in utf8, and some bytes sequences don't represent a character or are invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with string `a` which appears to follow python's hex escaping rules, you can decode it to a bytes object plus length of string decoded.

```
>>> a = "\\xe8\\xaa\\x9e\\xe8\\xa8\\x80"
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.escape_decode(a)
(b'\xe8\xaa\x9e\xe8\xa8\x80', 24)
```

You don't need the length here, so just get item 0. Now its time for some guessing. Assuming that this string actually represented a utf-8 encoding, you now have a bytes array that you can decode

```
>>> codecs.escape_decode(a)[0].decode('utf-8')
'語言'
```

If the underlying encoding was different (say, a Windows CJK code page), you'd have to decode with its decoder.

Comment: Thank you, it works:) Btw, could you explain a little bit how `codecs.escape_decode()` works under the hood? I've been searching for doc about this function but couldn't find any, `help(escape_decode)` doesn't give me any information either.

Comment: I _think_ that `escape_decode` turns around and calls the parser's literal string decode logic. If the string were `a = "\xe8\xaa\x9e\xe8\xa8\x80"` (single backslashes) the literal string parser would make the bytes you want. By calling `escape_decode` you are essentially calling the literal string parser a second time. I didn't realize it has no docs.

Comment: sadly the doc and the usage seems a very-old problem ... (ref: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059682/7860292), [2](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74773)

Answer (score 0):

Text like this could make a valid Python bytes literal. Assuming we don't have to worry about invalid input, we can simply construct a string that looks like the corresponding source code, and use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to interpret it that way (this [is safe, unlike using `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673)). Finally we decode the resulting `bytes` as UTF-8. Thus:

```
>>> a = "\\xe8\\xaa\\x9e\\xe8\\xa8\\x80"
>>> ast.literal_eval(f"b'{a}'")
b'\xe8\xaa\x9e\xe8\xa8\x80'
>>> ast.literal_eval(f"b'{a}'").decode('utf-8')
'語言'
```

Comment: Modeled on @Barmar's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68751612/523612 . I decided that this version of the question should be the canonical, but it was missing this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Such a codec is missing in stdlib. My package [all-escapes](https://github.com/wimglenn/all-escapes) registers a codec which can be used:

```
>>> a = "\\xe8\\xaa\\x9e\\xe8\\xa8\\x80"
>>> a.encode('all-escapes').decode()
'語言'
```