# How Python decodes UTF8 Encoding in String Format

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

Now there is a string of utf-8：

```
s = '\\346\\235\\216\\346\\265\\267\\347\\216\\211'
```

I need to decode it, but now I only do it in this way：

```
result = eval(bytes(f"b'{s}'", encoding="utf8")).decode('utf-8')
```

This is not safe, so is there a better way?

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of the unsafe `eval()`

Comment: A super round-about way: `s.encode('latin-1').decode("unicode_escape").encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` see the linked duplicate. Hoenstly, if safety is your concern, you can just use `ast.literal_eval`, it is almost clear-er for me. `unicode-escape` encoding is a bit arcane

Comment: `ast.literal_eval("b'"+s+"'").decode('utf8')` -> `'李海玉'`.  Shorter but not necessarily clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()`, it's not unsafe.

Then you don't need to call `bytes()`, since it will return a byte string.

```
result = ast.literal_eval(f"b'{s}'").decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you very much！I've tried literal before_ Eval, but an error is reported due to bytes()

Comment: This answer would break if `s` contains a single quote, for example. The linked answer is a safer approach IMHO, without involving parsing of Python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Might be what you are hoping to get ... :

```py
'\\346\\235\\216\\346\\265\\267\\347\\216\\211'.encode('utf8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do `decoded_string = s.decode("utf8")`

Comment: `decode()` is a bytes method, not a string method.