# python subprocess newlines are escaped

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running an mysql query in the command line using subprocess.Popen

```
process = subprocess.Popen(conarray, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

r = process.stdout.readlines()

stdout = [x.decode('utf8').rstrip() for x in r]
```

later I write the output in a file

```
f = open(file_name, 'w+', encoding='utf8')
f.write(templates[idx])
```

It works fine but for some reason all newlines(\n) and tabs(\t) are escaped.

```
\t<div id="container">\n\t\t<a name="top"
```

Any idea on how I can fix that ?

Comment: What is printed if you do `print(templates[idx])`?

Comment: the value is already escaped at that point, so i'm guessing it has to be something from the query `[mysql, '--default-character-set=utf8', '-u', user, '-h', host, dbname, "-e %s" % query]`

Comment: Could you show the code that makes `templates` ?

Comment: it's basically stdout the full code is here https://github.com/ionutvmi/SublimeMybbTplEditor/blob/master/mybb-tpl.py#L97

Comment: with .decode('unicode_escape') it seems to parse the new lines correctly but it doesn't convert chars like `ńńńńń`

Comment: I meant print each lines, not the whole one: `for line in r: print(line)`

Comment: it prints something like this `b'\\t\\t\\t<tr>\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t<td class="trow_sep" colspan="5">{$lang->active_warnings}</td>\\n\\t\\t\\t</tr>\r\n'`

Comment: How about `for line in r: print(line.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: `\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t<td class="trow1" colspan="5" align="center">{$lang->no_warnings}</td>\n\t\t\t</tr>
`

Comment: It seems like the escaped string is from the table you are quering on. You'd better check the part that insert that data into the table.

Comment: i already checked the data is correct there, I'm guessing they are escaped like that when I run subprocess.Popen() since the query result is one per line, to revert that I was doing `.decode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: Do you mean if you run the command in command line (not through Python subprocess), does it print non-escaped version?

Comment: yes in the command line they are showed properly http://puu.sh/aL9nN/cba8d374b7.png

Comment: Please run the following program: http://ideone.com/ueiCzE  (once with the given command, and once with your mysql command). and let me know what is printed.

Answer (score 1):

If you print the whole sequence object, `repr(list_object)` is printed. That's the way Python represent it.

```
>>> lst = ['\t<div id="container">\n\t\t<a name="top"']
>>> print(lst)
['\t<div id="container">\n\t\t<a name="top"']
>>> print(lst[0])
        <div id="container">
                <a name="top"
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in order to make them work I also needed to apply `unicode-escape` on that string.
But `unicode-escape` does NOT work in general.

```
>>> s = 'naïve \\t test'
>>> print(s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'))
naÃ¯ve   test
```

The best solution I could find is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519338/1579481)

Comment: Your string appears to have actual backslashes in it, rather than special characters merely represented with backslashes in the escape sequences. It probably went through an extra layer of escaping at some point. You'll need to figure out why that's happening and fix it.

Comment: here is the code to try it out on your computer https://gist.github.com/ionutvmi/a63e84c0402db7a266fd