# How can I convert special characters in a string back into escape sequences?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string like `'a\tb'`. If I `print` it, I will see `a    b`. But I want to see `a\tb` instead. How can I convert my string so it will print like that?

Comment: For the opposite (converting from backslash-escape sequences in the text to the corresponding data), see [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](/questions/4020539).

Answer (score 96):

```
print(repr('a\tb'))
```

[`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) gives you the "representation" of the string rather than the printing the string directly.

Comment: This will output the single quotes, which is ``'a\tb'``, not ``a\tb``.

Comment: @wyz23x2: That's true, you need to remove the quotes if you don't want them.

Comment: If the single quotes are not desirable then just strip them away like `print(repr('a\tb').strip("''")`

Answer (score 5):

## 1:

(Python 2)

```py
print ur'a\tb'
```

Note that in Python 3.x, `u''` is equal to `''`, and the prefix `ur` is invalid.
Python 3:

```py
print(r'a\tb')
```

## 2:

(Python 3)

```py
print('a\\tb')
```

## 3:

If you want to get the raw repr of an *existing* string, here is a small function:  (Python 3.6+)

```py
def raw(string: str, replace: bool = False) -> str:
    """Returns the raw representation of a string. If replace is true, replace a single backslash's repr \\ with \."""
    r = repr(string)[1:-1]  # Strip the quotes from representation
    if replace:
        r = r.replace('\\\\', '\\')
    return r
```

Examples:

```py
>>> print(raw('1234'))
1234
>>> print('\t\n'); print('='*10); print(raw('\t\n'))
    

==========
\t\n
>>> print(raw('\r\\3'))
\r\\3
>>> print(raw('\r\\3', True))
\r\3
```

Note this won't work for `\N{...}` Unicode escapes, only `r'\N{...}'` can. But I guess JSON doesn't have this :)

```py
>>> print(raw('\N{PLUS SIGN}'))
+
```

Comment: "Note this won't work for \N{...} Unicode escapes" Well, yes; just like it doesn't let you get `'\11'` nor `'\x09'` for a string that contains just a tab, but only `'\t'`. There are multiple possible representations for any given string, but `repr` can only possibly give back one of them.

Comment: "If replace is true, replace a single backslash's repr \\ with \" This is dangerous functionality to add. For example, `>>> print(raw('\\n', True))` will print `\n`. String literals like that are [deprecated](/q/52335970/) anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Please beware that *the problem is underspecified in general*. The built-in `repr` function will give you the *canonical* representation of the string as a string literal, as shown in the other answers. However, that may not be what you want.

For *every string except the empty string*, there are *multiple* ways of specifying the string contents. Even something as simple as `' '` could be written as `'\x20'`, or `'\u0020'`, or `'\U00000020'`. All of these are **the same string** (and that's ignoring the choice of enclosing quotes).

Python's choices are not always what you might expect. Newlines will be represented as `'\n'`, but backspace characters for example will be represented as a hex code, **not** as `'\b'`. On the other hand, even really fancy characters like emoji may very well be included literally, not escaped.

---

If you want to change that behaviour, you will have to write it yourself, after defining the *specific rules* you want to apply. One useful tool for this is [the `translate` method of strings](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), which can simply apply a mapping to each Unicode code point in the input. The string classmethod [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) can help with creating such a mapping, but that's still underpowered - you're stuck giving a specific set of code points to translate (and their translations), and then everything not specified is left alone.

If you want to convert large amounts of code points in a way that follows some kind of pattern, you might write a function for that. However, handling special cases, or multiple separate blocks of Unicode code points, could end up with a lot of tedious branching logic.

Here is my attempt to get the best of both worlds. We create a dict subclass that [implements `__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) to dispatch to a function handling an appropriate character range, and caches the result. We initialize it with an iterable or mapping of hard-coded values (per the base `dict` constructor), `*args` that give `(function, range)` pairs (the `function` will be used to compute the result for characters with numeric values falling in the `range`), and `**kwargs` (again per the base `dict` constructor). We will accept Unicode characters as the keys, although `translate` will pass the numeric code point values; so we also need to translate in the constructor.

```
class strtrans(dict):
    def __init__(self, iterable_or_mapping, *args, **kwargs):
        self._handlers = args
        temp = dict(iterable_or_mapping, **kwargs)
        super().__init__({ord(k): v for k, v in temp.items()})
    def __missing__(self, value):
        self[value] = value # if no handler, leave the character untouched
        for func, r in self._handlers:
            if value in r:
                self[value] = func(value)
                break
        return self[value] # not missing any more.
```

Let's test it:

```
>>> hardcoded = {'\n': '\\n', '\t': '\\t', '\b': '\\b'}
>>> # Using the `.format` method bound to a string is a quick way
>>> # to get a callable that accepts the input number and formats it in.
>>> # For uppercase, use :02X instead of :02x etc.
>>> backslash_x = ('\\x{:02x}'.format, range(256))
>>> backslash_u = ('\\u{:04x}'.format, range(256, 65536))
>>> backslash_U = ('\\U{:08x}'.format, range(65536, 0x110000))
>>> mapping = strtrans(hardcoded, backslash_x, backslash_u, backslash_U)
>>> test = '\n\t\b\x01\u4EBA\U0001F60A'
>>> print(test.translate(mapping)) # custom behaviour - note lowercase output
\n\t\b\x01\u4eba\U0001f60a
>>> print(repr(test)) # canonical representation, with enclosing quotes
'\n\t\x08\x01人'
>>> print(test) # your terminal's rendering may vary!

       人
```