# How to get text before carriage return

Tags: python, dictionary, carriage-return

I'm loading the following JSON into my program:

```
d =
[
  {
    "extraction_method": "lattice",
    "top": 18.0,
    "left": 18.0,
    "width": 575.682861328125,
    "height": 756.0,
    "right": 593.68286,
    "bottom": 774.0,
    "data": [
      [
        {
          "top": 108.0,
          "left": 18.0,
          "width": 575.682861328125,
          "height": 53.67376708984375,
          "text": "apple foo text\rhello world"
        },
...
```

I want to extract the substring "apple foo text" with:

```
print(d[0][0]['data'][0][0]['text'])
```

But it only returns `hello world`. I know it is because of the carriage return statement, but I'm not sure how to to print the substring before. How would I get just the text before the statement? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python print string like a raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520111/python-print-string-like-a-raw-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to string, you're using:

```
string = d[0][0]['data'][0][0]['text']
```

To get the desired substring split text on carriage return.

```
substring = string.split('\r')[0]
print(substring) # Result is apple foo text
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `repr`. Already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520111/python-print-string-like-a-raw-string)

```
Help on built-in function repr in module builtins:

repr(obj, /)
    Return the canonical string representation of the object.
    
    For many object types, including most builtins, eval(repr(obj)) == obj.
```

```py
print(repr(d[0][0]['data'][0][0]['text']))
```

output

```
'apple foo text\rhello world'
```