# How do I convert a string to an escape sequence in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, escaping

If I have a string containing four characters, for example:

```
'\\xf0'
```

How would I convert it to the escape sequence:

```
'\xf0'
```

I'm using Python 3.4.

Edit:
I was trying to convert the string into the character which the string's value represents.

Comment: What exactly is in these strings? You must not realize it, but your question is not clear. You could clafiry by stating how many characters are in the original and the resulting string (the result of `len(string)`.

Comment: Your original string is a escaped string and your expected output is a hex value, So pls correct your question.

Comment: @alexis Sorry, I'm [obviously] new to this, is that proper now?

Comment: Also you can not replace \ with \\ because one backslash assumed as  escape character by python so you need to replace the `\\x` with `\x`.

Comment: Your original string contains backslash, x, f, 0. Should the result be a single byte? (If so, it is _not_ an "escape sequence")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is interpret the escape sequences in the original string, to get the corresponding character(s). Don't compute them yourself, call a `decode()` method. In Python 3 you'll only find it on `bytes` objects (not `str`), so you need to convert to a `bytes` object and back:

```
>>> bytes("\\xf0\\xfa", "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
'ðú'
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020824/699305) for a more complete answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want..

```
literal_version = '\\xf0'
byte_version = bytes([int('0'+literal_version[1:], 16)])
```