# Escaping characters in Python, but ignoring already escaped characters

Tags: python, escaping, cgi

In one of my projects I'm using `cgi.escape()` to escape a set of titles that I get from a resource. These titles could be from Youtube or anywhere else, and may need to be escaped.

The issue I'm having is that if a title is already escaped from Youtube and I pass it into `cgi.escape()`, I end up getting double-escaped titles, which is messing up later parts of my project.

Is there a library that will escape strings but check if a piece is already escaped, and ignore it?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml

Comment: According to http://webhelpers2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/html/builder.html, webhelpers2 has a literal class, while literal.escape() returns literal instances and if given a literal to escape returns it unchanged.

Comment: `import html; s = """&gt;>"""; s = html.escape(html.unescape(s))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webhelpers2.html.builder.literal represents an "HTML literal string, which will not be further escaped".  It has an escape method for escaping HTML and returning a literal and a literal instance can be converted to a string with ''.join(literal_instance)

For example using Python 2.7.10:

from webhelpers2.html.builder import literal

```
e1 = literal.escape('& < >')
e1
Out[3]: literal(u'&amp; &lt; &gt;')

e2 = literal.escape(e1)
e2
Out[5]: literal(u'&amp; &lt; &gt;')

s = ''.join(e1)
s
Out[7]: u'&amp; &lt; &gt;'
```

With Python 3.4.3:

```
from webhelpers2.html.builder import literal

e1 = literal.escape('& < >')
e1
literal('&amp; &lt; &gt;')

e2 = literal.escape(e1)
e2
Out[5]: literal('&amp; &lt; &gt;')

s = ''.join(e1)
s
Out[7]: '&amp; &lt; &gt;'
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer was perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you know your input is already escaped, unescape it first. Then later escape it just before where it needs to be.

Answer (score -1):

You can [resolve the possibly-escaped strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python) first, then pass them to whatever escaping you're doing yourself.