# input() and literal unicode parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, unicode, unicode-literals

Using `input()` takes a backslash as a literal backslash so I am unable to parse a string input with unicode.

What I mean:

Pasting a string like `"\uXXXX\uXXXX\uXXXX"` into an `input()` call will become interpreted as `"\\uXXXX\\uXXXX\\uXXXX"` but I want it read `\u` as a single character instead of two separate characters.

Does anyone know how or if possible to make it happen?

Edit: I am taking input as above and converting it to ascii such as below..

```
import unicodedata

def Reveal(unicodeSol):
    solution = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicodeSol).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    print(solution)

while(True):
    UserInput = input("Paste Now: ")
    Reveal(UserInput)
```

Per the answer I marked, a correct solution would be:

```
import unicodedata
import ast

def Reveal(unicodeSol):
    solution = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicodeSol).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    print(solution)

while(True):
    UserInput = ast.literal_eval('"{}"'.format(input("Paste Now: ")))
    Reveal(UserInput)
```

Comment: What code are you using to print the string? Please show your output or interpreter session.

Comment: input() doesn't do any special parsing of escape sequences afaik, it just returns literally what the user typed. What would you want to happen if (for example) the user entered a malformed escape sequence? There is a way to solve this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: what is the source of such strings? If you need `ast.literal_eval()` or `unicode-escape` encoding; something is broken upstream. `input()` accepts and returns Unicode strings as is. What is `print(ascii(input('Paste Now: ")))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be sure that input would not contain quotes, you can convert the input into a string literal representation, by adding quotes in both ends , and then use `ast.literal_eval()` to evaluate it into a string. Example -

```
import ast
inp = input("Input : ")
res = ast.literal_eval('"{}"'.format(inp))
```

If the input can contain quotes you can replace double quotes with `r'\"'` before evaluating using ast.literal_eval .