# How can I convert literal escape sequences in a string to the corresponding bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I have a UTF-8 encoded string that comes from somewhere else that contains the characters `\xc3\x85lesund` (literal backslash, literal "x", literal "c", etc).

Printing it outputs the following:

```
\xc3\x85lesund
```

I want to convert it to a bytes variable:

```
b'\xc3\x85lesund'
```

To be able to encode:

```
'Ålesund'
```

How can I do this? I'm using python 3.4.

Comment: What's the `repr` of it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `\\xc3\\x85lesund`

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4020539/176646)

Comment: `s=u'\xc3\x85lesund'` then `bytearray(s, 'Latin-1')` or `bytearray(s, 'ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Exactly, sadly using the accepted answer some info is lost as the 2nd post states. It returns `Ãlesund`. Going to try the 2nd post approach with codecs.

Comment: @BillBell Doesn't work, it creates the byte array `bytearray(b'\\xc3\\x85lesund')`

Comment: Sorry. Of course not, you want *bytes*.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The 2nd poster's answer also didn't work yielded the same `Ãlesund`

Comment: The [third solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37059682/176646) works for me (although the method it uses is undocumented).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Eureka! It does work, awesome. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Using `unicode_escape`

**TL;DR** You can decode bytes using the `unicode_escape` encoding to convert `\xXX` and `\uXXXX` escape sequences to the corresponding characters:

```
>>> r'\xc3\x85lesund'.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1')
b'\xc3\x85lesund'
```

---

First, encode the string to bytes so it can be decoded:

```
>>> r'\xc3\x85あ'.encode('utf-8')
b'\\xc3\\x85\xe3\x81\x82'
```

(I changed the string to show that this process works even for characters outside of Latin-1.)

Here's how each character is encoded (note that あ is encoded into multiple bytes):

- `\` (U+005C) -> 0x5c
- `x` (U+0078) -> 0x78
- `c` (U+0063) -> 0x63
- `3` (U+0033) -> 0x33
- `\` (U+005C) -> 0x5c
- `x` (U+0078) -> 0x78
- `8` (U+0038) -> 0x38
- `5` (U+0035) -> 0x35
- `あ` (U+3042) -> 0xe3, 0x81, 0x82

Next, decode the bytes as `unicode_escape` to replace each escape sequence with its corresponding character:

```
>>> r'\xc3\x85あ'.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
'Ã\x85ã\x81\x82'
```

Each escape sequence is converted to a separate character; each byte that is not part of an escape sequence is converted to the character with the corresponding ordinal value:

- `\\xc3` -> U+00C3
- `\\x85` -> U+0085
- `\xe3` -> U+00E3
- `\x81` -> U+0081
- `\x82` -> U+0082

Finally, encode the string to bytes again:

```
>>> r'\xc3\x85あ'.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1')
b'\xc3\x85\xe3\x81\x82'
```

Encoding as Latin-1 simply converts each character to its ordinal value:

- U+00C3 -> 0xc3
- U+0085 -> 0x85
- U+00E3 -> 0xe3
- U+0081 -> 0x81
- U+0082 -> 0x82

And voilà, we have the byte sequence you're looking for.

## Using `codecs.escape_decode`

As an alternative, you can use the `codecs.escape_decode` method to interpret escape sequences in a bytes to bytes conversion, as [user19087](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2626865/user19087) posted in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059682) to a similar question:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.escape_decode(r'\xc3\x85lesund'.encode('utf-8'))[0]
b'\xc3\x85lesund'
```

However, `codecs.escape_decode` is undocumented, so I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Both solutions worked wonderfully, if it's not asking too much can you give me the reasoning behind `.encode('latin-1')`?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida I added a more detailed explanation. Sorry that took so long!

Comment: It's a shame I can only upvote once! Thanks a bunch.