# Python3: sys.stdout giving different results on linux and windows

Tags: python, character-encoding, stdout

The output of code varies on Linux and Windows.I am not much familiar with encodings, which is what this problem seems to involve.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from treelib import Tree
from io import StringIO

# creating and populating tree
tree = Tree()
tree.create_node("Harry", "harry")  # root node
tree.create_node("Jane", "jane", parent="harry")
tree.create_node("Bill", "bill", parent="harry")
tree.create_node("Diane", "diane", parent="jane")
tree.create_node("Mary", "mary", parent="diane")
tree.create_node("Mark", "mark", parent="jane")

# var to store standard output

output = StringIO()

sys.stdout = output

tree.show()
# restoring standard output to console
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

tree_structure = output.getvalue()

print(tree_structure)
```

I am getting expected output on Linux but on Windows result have chars encoded as **\xNN**.

Linux output:

```
Harry
├── Bill
└── Jane
    ├── Diane
    │   └── Mary
    └── Mark
```

Windows Output:

```
b'Harry\n\xe2\x94\x9c\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 Bill\n\xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 Jane\n    \xe2\x94\x9c\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 Diane\n    \xe2\x94\x82   \xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 Mary\n    \xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 Mark\n'
```

Though the result of `sys.stdout.encoding` was `'utf-8'` both on windows and linux.

The closest I could reach to the expected output was by adding following before print statement:

```
#removing b'' from string
tree_structure = tree_structure[2:-2]
# converting to bytes
tree_structure = bytes(tree_structure,'utf-8')

tree_structure = tree_structure.decode('unicode_escape')

print(tree_structure)
```

output afterward:

```
Harry
âââ Bill
âââ Jane
    âââ Diane
    â   âââ Mary
    âââ Mark
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the expected output by using [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059682/8287605) helped me. 
Using codec worked.

```
tree_structure = codecs.escape_decode(bytes(tree_structure, "utf-8"))[0].decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with your Windows terminal and not with your code.

Try setting `chcp 65001` in your console, which changes the code page to UTF-8.
`print("├")` works for me after that.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490874.aspx

Comment: Setting code page to UTF-8 didn't work. It still shows the same output.