# Convert string of hex to hex value

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, ascii

How to print ♠ at terminal where I read string `u"\u2660"` from `data.txt`

```
data = "./data.txt"

with open(data, 'r') as source:
        for info in source: print(info)
```

`u"\u2660"` is what I get in the terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python) ?

Answer (score 0):

The string `u"\u2660"` is just a plain text in a txt file. It needs to be interpreted by python interpreter to become a string which represents the unicode character. And you can use `eval` to do that.

```
>>> a=r'u"\u2660"'
>>> print(a)
u"\u2660"
>>> b = eval(a)
>>> print(b)
♠
```

Comment: Not just posting an answer, you could add little explanation which understand the solution better to OP and future readers as well.

Comment: please explain your answer