# how to preserve newline symbol in option in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to enter newline in option such as `--opt hello\nworld\n`

Here is code snippet:

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--embed', dest='embed', default=None, help='embed info')
    return parser.parse_args()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    print args.embed # It shows: hellonworldn
```

I execute like below:

```
python test.py --embed hello\nworld\n
```

But it always failed ans shows no newline symbols:

```
hellonworldn
```

I also execute like below:

```
python test.py --embed "hello\nworld\n"
```

But it still failed ans print without newline:

```
hello\nworld\n
```

How to reserve the newline symbol and make the output like below?

```
hello
world
```

Comment: Did you try `python test.py --embed "hello\nworld\n"`?

Comment: @taras yes I tried, the result is the same

Comment: [this post](https://superuser.com/a/163521/250313) discusses possible solutions

Comment: @taras I tried. It's the same even I use single quotes.

Comment: And what about escaping `\n`?

Comment: @taras what do mean? Can you give an example? thx lots

Comment: I meant passing `\n` as `\\n`. '\\' is evaluated as '\', so you will get '\n' literally, rather than a newline character.

Comment: @taras when I enter "hello\\nworld\\n" , it prints "hello\nworld\n". If I enter "hello\\\nworld\\\n", it shows the same .

Comment: If changed to single quote. When I enter 'hello\\nworld\\n' , it prints hello\\nworld\\n. If I enter 'hello\\\nworld\\\n', it prints hello\\\nworld\\\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite reproduce the problem:

```
C:\Users\pi\Desktop>C:\Anaconda3\python test.py --embed hello\nworld\n
hello\nworld\n
```

So the string is read correctly, interpreting the backslashes as literal backslashes. If you want them to be parsed, use

```
print args.embed.decode("string_escape")
```

In Python 3, it would look a little different (see [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020539/20670))

Comment: Aside from the official [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), and the [`codecs` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html), there is the classic Joel blog post https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ (from 2003, still relevant). Also very good: Anything by Ned Batchelder: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: By the way, why Python 2.7? Python 3 has been out for ages, Python 2 has only received bug fixes since 2010...

Comment: Because I tried program myself in Python2.7. I'll do my best to transfer to python3