# discord.py reading txt and sending message with line breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Still new to coding and have been searching but no luck in finding what I have done wrong. 
Trying to make a discord bot read a text file pick a line and send the message but I can't get \n working for line breaks.

```
if os.path.exists('text.txt'):
    lines = open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()
    text = random.choice(lines)
    await client.send_message(member, text)
```

I have a text file called text.txt that has this inside

```
testing this now 
testing
```

but when it sends the message I Don't get the line break. Everything is on the one line.

Comment: splitlines() will split with \n as the separator (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm)

Comment: Does your text file have a line break or the two characters `\n`?

Comment: Test file is the two characters '\n' So one line in the txt file is. testing this now \n testing. It sends this message but also sends the \n as text 
EG. http://prntscr.com/ly45pi

Comment: See [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020824/6779307)

Answer (score 0):

You literally wrote `"\n"` to your text file? Well, `'\n'` is just a combination of symbols `'\'` and `'n'` (two chars), not the `'\n'` character. It's an another kind of character. It can't be displayed. In order to insert a newline to your file, just use the capabilities of your text editor (Enter).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have multiple lines in my text file and to pick a random line for each message. But each message Needs to have a newline in it.If I do it this way Can only have one message not multiple.

Answer (score -1):

This is my first time answer but I hope this helps.

```py
if os.path.exists('text.txt'):
    with open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8','r') as lines:
        #lines now has a list of each line
        text = random.choice(lines)

    await client.send_message(member, text)
```