# How do I convert unicode characters (ASCII 10) to text in Python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, webrequest, unicode-escapes

I'm using http.client.HTTPConnection request result in Python. Result is like :

```
\u000aFull command = \/opt\/ericsson\/amos\/moshell\/mobatch \u000a Hello
```

I want to convert this into standart text for my next parsing operation

```
response = connection.getresponse()
html_response = response.read().decode('ascii')
```

What I'm expecting here as result is

```
Full command = /opt/ericsson/amos/moshell/mobatch
Hello
```

But its not even converts, I directly get the same thing.
I already tried regular expression replacements but I dont want to struggle in all characters in ASCII 10 list.

Comment: Does `.decode("unicode-escape")` work?

Comment: If you `print(html_response)` do you get what you need?

Comment: .decode("unicode-escape") @filmor its working only "\" characters. Its not helping in \u000a.

Comment: @MarkRansom no still as it is

Comment: Check the second answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: I made a mistake @filmor unicode-escape works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. decode with unicode_escape ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings))
2. remove extra back slashes

sample code:

```
s = '\u000aFull command = \/opt\/ericsson\/amos\/moshell\/mobatch \u000a Hello'  
print s.decode('unicode_escape').replace('\\', '')

Full command = /opt/ericsson/amos/moshell/mobatch  
 Hello
```