# How to format escape sequences inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, formatting, escaping

I want to import a value inside a function which will work as an escape sequence on the string the function should print. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def vhf(c):
    print "...I want this \%s escape sequence" % c

vhf('n')
```

The output is :

```
...I want this \n escape sequence
```

But I want it to be:

```
...I want this
escape sequence
```

Comment: If possible, you should switch to Python v3.7+ - https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aren't working with string literals, don't use escape sequences in the *function*.

```
def vhf(c):
    print "...I want this %s escape sequence" % (c,)

vhf('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python) thread, which discussed a similar issue, you could make use of the built-in String method [decode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) together with the *'string-escape'* [codec](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings):

```py
def vhf(c):
    s = "...I want this \\" + c + " escape sequence"
    print s.decode('string_escape')
```