# Extract Bytes From String That Contains Bytes Data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python 3 and trying to extract a message from a bytes array that contains both string and bytes in the message.

I'm unable to extract the bytes message from the decoded bytes array.

1. Firstly, I decode the bytes array.
2. Then I do a split on the decoded array.
3. I get string values upon splitting the array.

I tried to use `bytes(v) for v in rest.split()` function to try and get the bytes array and then decode it, but wasn't able to.

```
# The message chunk:
chunk = b"1568077849\n522\nb'l5:d4:auth53:\xc3\x99\xc3\xac\x1fH\xc2\xa3ei6eli1eee'\n"

# I split the chunk into sub categories for further processing:
_, size, rest = (chunk.decode("utf-8")).split('\n', 2)

# _ contains "1568077849"
# size contains "522" 
# rest contains "b'l5:d4:auth53:\xc3\x99\xc3\xac\x1fH\xc2\xa3ei6eli1eee'"
```

I'm supposed to be able to decode the rest variable (rest.decode("utf-8")), but since it's getting stored as string, I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I convert that to bytes and then decode the value.

The expected result: `l5:d4:auth53:ÙìH£ei6eli1eee`

Comment: how did you get this string ? It seems someone create this string in wrong way.

Comment: You could use slicing `rest = rest[2:-2]`

Comment: It's coming in from a server ```request = reader._build_request(chunk_meta)
    chunk = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()```

Comment: as @nathancy mentioned you have to slice it  and then you should have correct string `l5:d4:auth53:ÙìH£ei6eli1eee`

Comment: @nathancy I need to be able to get the value in bytes to be able to decode it correctly. Currently, your solution is still giving rest as a string ``` print(isinstance(rest, bytes)) -> False ```

Comment: I don't fully understand, maybe this?? `rest = bytes(rest[2:-2].encode('utf-8'))
`. Then the type is bytes `print(isinstance(rest, bytes))` -> `True`

Comment: @nathancy The rest is getting stored as a string object ```l5:d4:auth53:\xc3\x99\xc3\xac\x1fH\xc2\xa3ei6eli1eee```, so if we encode it, its becoming a byte object ```b'l5:d4:auth53:\\xc3\\x99\\xc3\\xac\\x1fH\\xc2\\xa3ei6eli1eee'```. Which if we decode doesn't give the expected answer ```l5:d4:auth53:ÙìH£ei6eli1eee```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print your final result:

```py
chunk = b"1568077849\n522\nb'l5:d4:auth53:\xc3\x99\xc3\xac\x1fH\xc2\xa3ei6eli1eee'\n"

l1 = chunk.decode('utf-8').split()[2:]  # Initial decode
#  slice out the embedded byte string "b'  '" characters
l1_string = ''.join([x[:-2] if x[0] != 'b' else x[2:] for x in l1])
l1_bytes = l1_string.encode('utf-8')
l1_final = l1_bytes.decode('utf-8')

print('Results')
print(f'l1_string is {l1_string}')
print(f'l1_bytes is {l1_bytes}')
print(f'l1_final is {l1_final}')
```

```
Results
l1_string is l5:d4:auth53:ÙìH£ei6eli1ee
l1_bytes is b'l5:d4:auth53:\xc3\x99\xc3\xacH\xc2\xa3ei6eli1ee'
l1_final is l5:d4:auth53:ÙìH£ei6eli1ee
```

Comment: Thanks Dave !! Took sometime to decode the answer :)

Comment: Dave, I just came across the data and its coming in as: ```chunk = b"1568077849\n522\nb'l5:d4:auth53:\\xc3\\x99\\xc3\\xac\\x1fH\\xc2\\xa3ei6eli1eee'\n"```. There are two double slashes in the input. So the above solution is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the expected output this way:

```
 _, size, rest = (chunk.decode("utf-8")).split('\n', 2)
 rest = bytes(rest.replace("b'", "").replace("'", ""), "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
```

Got the clue from this post:
[Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)