# How to combine a backslash and another char into an escape char in Python, manually?

Tags: python, parsing, escaping

I'm writing a script in Python that parses text from a file. One thing I need is to be able to read two chars that make up an escape char, like `\` and `n` -> `'\n'`. So basically, how can I take a string `"\"` and combine it with `"n"` to become the escape char `"\n"`?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Solved in another question: [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are a few different ways you could do that, and the most appropriate one depends on the case. What kind of text/file is it? Is it a standard format, like JSON or source code in some language?

Comment: Standard text file. This here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python