# How to get sys.argv as below in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, sys

I would like to get the sys.argv as below:

```py
# main.py

import sys

arguments = sys.argv
print(arguments[1])
```

```
$ python main.py \\
```

I want: \

But this comes instead: \\

Comment: What shell are you using?  What happens if you do "echo \\" to your shell (without the quotes, and without invoking Python)?

Comment: Doing  ```echo \\``` gives me the output  ```\\``` (I am using Command Prompt)

Comment: Ok, so your command prompt doesn't recognize \ as an escape character, and is passing \\ straight through to Python.  The actual argument that Python sees is \\.  So the question is, when given \\, how do you want to handle it in Python?  Can you just type a single \, or does it have to be \\?  It's showing you exactly what you typed.

Comment: if you want 1 then enter only 1 argument. or use a unique function on all your arguements.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Interesting, I'm using a shell that recognizes \ as an escape character (bash) and I get the same problem as the OP. For instance running `python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" \\` stores "\\" in argv instead of "\". But running `python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" \` doesn't store "\" in argv, because bash treats it like a newline separator.

Comment: @Michael When you `print(sys.argv)`, you are printing a list of strings. `print` converts the list to a string by calling `str()` on it, and `str()` on lists call `repr()` on the items, so you should be seeing quotes and backslashes which aren't really there.

Comment: @Michael Read Ture's explanation.  Also, try the following:  `print("\\")` vs. `print(["\\"])`.  The string is the same in both cases (a single \ ), but the latter uses `repr` to show it since it's in a list, rather than being printed directly.  Note that with `repr`, you also get quotes around the string, which implies that escapes will be shown.