# ini file in raw string: new lines are not interpreted

Tags: python, string, newline, ini, configparser

I have an ini file brought from a Get request. I want to write this string to a file. when I write this string to a file or print this string the new lines are not interpreted

```
userData = str(requests.get(url).content)
file = open(FileINI, "w")
file.write(userData)
file.close()
```

userData contains something like :

```
[Foo]\n\nIsProduction = 0\n\n[Bar]\nkey = key1\n
```

The FileINI content is :

```
[Foo]\n\nIsProduction = 0\n\n[Bar]\nkey = key1\n
```

I tried the repr function, and configParser but no use

Update

I found out that the response contains "\\n" when converted to string, thats why when I print it it does give me only \n. So a replace \\n to \n made the job

Comment: What  does a `print(userData)` display?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python — does this answers your question?