# How to read html input \t as a tab instead of as \\t

Tags: python, django, string

Okay, so I tried to look for a solution for about one hour and couldn't find anything that works. Let me describe the problem.

I have a simple html form where the user uploads a file (.csv) and then also gives a delimiter for that file that I will be using to read it. The problem arises when the user submits a tab delimiter `\t`. When I try to access it in django

```
delimiter = request.POST['delimiter']
```

I get a string `\\t` which just corresponds to a string `\t` (not a tab). Is there a way to read the input as a tab or somehow convert anything with the escape character to the right form. The only way I figured out would be to do

```
delimiter.replace('\\t', '\t')
```

But then I would have to do this for `\n` etc. so there has to be a better way.

Comment: No, the *representation* of `\t` is `'\\t'. In reality it is a tab character.

Comment: I think this is happening inside the HTML form, immediately upon the user entering `\t`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python) (Essentially you just need to write `delimiter = delimiter.encode().decode("unicode_escape")`)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that worked!!! thank you :) I read about `decode("unicode_escape")` but it didn't work without `encode()`