# Constructing strings with escaped values (variables) that are unknown until runtime

Tags: python, string, iterator, escaping, byte

Let's say I have an escaped hex value in a string:

```
val = "\x70"
```

and the function

```
def foo(input):
  for byte in bytes(input, "utf-8"):
    print(byte)
```

If I call

```
foo(val) #prints 112
```

The function works as desired. But what if I don't know the value of the hex code I want to escape, yet want to escape it and iterate through it the same way?

```
unknown_until_runtime = "70"
val = "\x" + unknown_until_runtime
```

Results in a

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

I have the option of escaping the escape character, but this then breaks the functionality of the iterator in foo():

```
unknown_until_runtime = "70"
val = "\\x" + unknown_until_runtime
foo(val) #prints 92 120 55 48
```

Instead of escaping the entire byte as intended, this "string construction method" does not escape anything, and simply creates a "string of chars" that does not function the way I want it. And for the life of me, I find a way to obtain this "escaped byte string" when the values are unknown until runtime. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your function to the following, it should work:

```
def foo(input_str)
    for byte in bytes('\\x' + input_str, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'):
        print(byte)
```

Solution inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020824/13990016).