# python csv reader and ignoring \n

Tags: python-3.x

So this is probably a stupid question but it is annoying and bothering me and I cannot seem to find the answer googling. Why when reading and then printing from a csv file does \n get printed as \n and not become a newline?

Comment: Are you printing the `list`s `csv.reader` is returning directly? It should be removing newlines as part of the parsing if they're not embedded in a field, but `list`s print the `repr` of their contents, and the `repr` of `str` is quoted and uses escapes for the various types of whitespace (aside from the space character itself).

Comment: I am storing the line  of csv.reader in a variable and printing variable[0]. So if my csvfile has a\na it prints out a\na exactly like that.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [MCVE]; it shouldn't do what you describe (unless the file contains a literal backslash followed by n in the first field, so be sure to include a little sample data too), but your description could be less accurate than the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding the literal string/bytestring wiht something like:

```
my_string = r"asdasd\nasdaasd"
print(my_string)
print(bytes(my_string, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"))
```

Check for more: [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)