# New line character as user input in Python

Tags: python, string, user-input, newline

While joining items in a list and printing them out as a string, I wanted to take user input for a character that will be used a separator. What if the separator is to be a newline? What can the user input be? Because if the user input is simply '\n' then that is being used literally ('\n' is being added as text).

Code that I ran:

```
tojoin = ['Hello','Its','Me','Uh','Mario']
merge = tojoin[0]
sepchar = input("Enter the character(s) with which you wish to separate the list items:  ")
#User input = '\n'
for i in tojoin:
    merge = merge+sepchar+i
print(merge)
```

Expected output:

Hello

It's

Me

Uh

Mario

Actual output:
Hello\nHello\nIts\nMe\nUh\nMario

How can I get to the expected output?

Comment: Additional new line has been added in the 'Expected output' section of this question because the words weren't being shown on separate lines otherwise. The expected output is: each word on a separate line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the following line of code after the input

```
sepchar = bytes(sepchar, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)