# How can convert '\\u5de5' into '\u5de5'?

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-unicode

They are different:

```
len('\\u5de5')
6
len('\u5de5')
1
```

How can write a function to convert `\\u5de5` into `\u5de5`?

```
def con_str(arg):
    some_code_here
    return result

con_str('\\u5de5')
\u5de5
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020539/5320906) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')` for doubled *Reverse Solidi*, see [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
def con_str(arg):
    result = arg.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')
    return result

con_str('\\u5de5')
```

> ```
> '工'
> ```