# Read b-string from file

Tags: python, string

I have a txt file that contains lines like `b'111\r\n222\r\n333'`.

When I read the file with

```
with open('raw2.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = f.read().splitlines()
```

then the b-rows are turned into regular strings.

```
"b'111\\r\\n222\\r\\n333'"
```

If I read as 'rb', these lines become binary

```
b"b'111\\r\\n222\\r\\n333'"
```

How do I read the file correctly so that they look like:

```
b'111\r\n222\r\n333'
```

?

Thanks

Comment: This question likely has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73243686/1328439

Comment: A less wacky solution would have been to save the file as binary in the first place if that's what you actually want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the literal syntax.

```
import ast

with open('raw2.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = list(map(ast.literal_eval, f.read().splitlines()))
```