# Best way to escape and unescape strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, escaping

Does Ruby have any built-in method for escaping *and* unescaping strings?  In the past, I've used regular expressions; however, it occurs to me that Ruby probably does such conversions internally all the time. Perhaps this functionality is exposed somewhere.

So far I've come up with these functions.  They work, but they seem a bit hacky:

```
def escape(s)
  s.inspect[1..-2]
end

def unescape(s)
  eval %Q{"#{s}"}
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Escape for what purpose? For use in Ruby source?

Comment: @mu is too ahort: Yes, escaping as per Ruby source rules.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ruby 2.5 added [`String#undump`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-undump) as a complement to [`String#dump`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-dump):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> dumped_newline = "\n".dump
=> "\"\\n\""
irb(main):002:0> undumped_newline = dumped_newline.undump
=> "\n"
```

With it:

```
def escape(s)
  s.dump[1..-2]
end

def unescape(s)
  "\"#{s}\"".undump
end

$irb
irb(main):001:0> escape("\n \" \\")
=> "\\n \\\" \\\\"
irb(main):002:0> unescape("\\n \\\" \\\\")
=> "\n \" \\"
```

Answer (score 20):

There are a bunch of escaping methods, some of them:

```
# Regexp escapings
>> Regexp.escape('\*?{}.')   
=> \\\*\?\{\}\. 
>> URI.escape("test=100%")
=> "test=100%25"
>> CGI.escape("test=100%")
=> "test%3D100%25"
```

So, its really depends on the issue you need to solve. But I would avoid using inspect for escaping.

Update - there is a dump, inspect uses that, and it looks like it is what you need:

```
>> "\n\t".dump
=> "\"\\n\\t\""
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid `inspect` too.  I was hoping Ruby's own string escaping code might be available.  Something along the lines of `Ruby.escape("\t") => "\\t"` and `Ruby.unescape("\\t") => "\t"`

Answer (score 19):

Caleb function was the nearest thing to the reverse of String #inspect I was able to find, however it contained two bugs:

- \\ was not handled correctly.
- \x.. retained the backslash.

I fixed the above bugs and this is the updated version:

```
UNESCAPES = {
    'a' => "\x07", 'b' => "\x08", 't' => "\x09",
    'n' => "\x0a", 'v' => "\x0b", 'f' => "\x0c",
    'r' => "\x0d", 'e' => "\x1b", "\\\\" => "\x5c",
    "\"" => "\x22", "'" => "\x27"
}

def unescape(str)
  # Escape all the things
  str.gsub(/\\(?:([#{UNESCAPES.keys.join}])|u([\da-fA-F]{4}))|\\0?x([\da-fA-F]{2})/) {
    if $1
      if $1 == '\\' then '\\' else UNESCAPES[$1] end
    elsif $2 # escape \u0000 unicode
      ["#$2".hex].pack('U*')
    elsif $3 # escape \0xff or \xff
      [$3].pack('H2')
    end
  }
end

# To test it
while true
    line = STDIN.gets
    puts unescape(line)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the updates! I'd have fixed it if you commented, though.

Comment: @antirez this is very useful. I've incorporated it into a puppet module I made as a [puppet function](https://github.com/gene1wood/puppet-credstash/blob/4f5879192ab07bd8de07daeb49ab50e9d00ff563/lib/puppet/parser/functions/unescape.rb)

Comment: @antirez This is the best answer I found so far. Just a tip, instead of using hexadecimal, the actual escaped chars can be used. For example, instead of `"\x0a"`, it can be `"\n"`. I think this is more clear.

Answer (score 16):

*Update*: I no longer agree with my own answer, but I'd prefer not to delete it since I suspect that others may go down this wrong path, and there's already been a lot of discussion of this answer and it's alternatives, so I think it still contributes to the conversation, but please don't use this answer in real code.

If you don't want to use `eval`, but are willing to use the `YAML` module, you can use it instead:

```rb
require 'yaml'

def unescape(s)
  YAML.load(%Q(---\n"#{s}"\n))
end
```

The advantage to `YAML` over `eval` is that it is presumably safer. `cane` disallows all usage of `eval`. I've seen recommendations to use `$SAFE` along with `eval`, but that is not available via JRuby currently.

For what it is worth, Python does have native support for [unescaping backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python).

Comment: Thank you. I took your idea and applied it to JSON, `JSON.parse("[#{s}]").first`

Comment: seems YAML code and EVAL code are different. For example 
s = "\\xD8\\x96a"
YAML.load(%Q(---\n"#{s}"\n))
(eval %Q{"#{s}"})
returns different values

Answer (score 13):

Ruby's `inspect` can help:

```
    "a\nb".inspect
=> "\"a\\nb\""
```

Normally if we print a string with an embedded line-feed, we'd get:

```
puts "a\nb"
a
b
```

If we print the inspected version:

```
puts "a\nb".inspect
"a\nb"
```

Assign the inspected version to a variable and you'll have the escaped version of the string.

To undo the escaping, `eval` the string:

```
puts eval("a\nb".inspect)
a
b
```

---

I don't really like doing it this way. It's more of a curiosity than something I'd do in practice.

Comment: Danger will Robinson, Danger! Using eval to unescape the string is really dangerous if the string happens to be user input! It would allow the user to effectively run just about anything.

Comment: Yes, if it is user input it should be sanitized first. But, it can't run anything, only what the user ID running the code could run, which, in a correctly written application will be reduced privileges or in a chroot sandbox.

Comment: You are right. But in reality, much of of the value on a box is not the operating system files, but your data. You chroot your rails app as much as you like, but it still needs access to your database. So whilst your attacker can't do "everything", they can do a lot, including dumping all your data.

Answer (score 12):

YAML's `::unescape` doesn't seem to escape quote characters, e.g. `'` and `"`. I'm guessing this is by design, but it makes me sad.

You definitely do not want to use `eval` on arbitrary or client-supplied data.

This is what I use. Handles everything I've seen and doesn't introduce any dependencies.

```
UNESCAPES = {
    'a' => "\x07", 'b' => "\x08", 't' => "\x09",
    'n' => "\x0a", 'v' => "\x0b", 'f' => "\x0c",
    'r' => "\x0d", 'e' => "\x1b", "\\\\" => "\x5c",
    "\"" => "\x22", "'" => "\x27"
}

def unescape(str)
  # Escape all the things
  str.gsub(/\\(?:([#{UNESCAPES.keys.join}])|u([\da-fA-F]{4}))|\\0?x([\da-fA-F]{2})/) {
    if $1
      if $1 == '\\' then '\\' else UNESCAPES[$1] end
    elsif $2 # escape \u0000 unicode
      ["#$2".hex].pack('U*')
    elsif $3 # escape \0xff or \xff
      [$3].pack('H2')
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: To handle `"\u{12345}"` type encoding for extended unicode characters (such as emoji), I added `|u{([\da-fA-F]+)}` to the regexp like `/\\(?:([#{keys}])|u([\da-fA-F]{4})|u{([\da-fA-F]+)})|\\0?x([\da-fA-F]{2})/`, changed the `$3` references to `$4`, and inserted `elsif $3; ["#$3".hex].pack('U*')` between the $2 and $4 sections.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that `Shellwords.escape` will do what you're looking for

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape