# How to get the string from its inspect result?

Tags: ruby

I know I could use `eval` to get the string back like below:

```
"".inspect  == "\"\"" # true
eval("\"\"") == ""    # true
```

But besides `eval`, is there an another way to do it?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you need to do this? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `String::class_eval{"\"\""}` might do what you want.

Comment: @theTinMan What I want to do is get `""` from string `"\"\""`, for example. I have some data which is the result of string's inspect result, I need to revert them back to the orignal string.

Comment: `#inspect` in your case merely puts double quotes around the escaped string, just like `#dump`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to escape and unescape strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639642/whats-the-best-way-to-escape-and-unescape-strings)

Comment: Yes, we know you want to recover a string created by inspect, but that's not how data should be transferred or serialized, so if you are receiving strings like that, there is a code-smell in the air. That's something that might need to be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `""` is an empty string. `"\"\""` is something completely else: A string that, when it is fed to something, yields your `""` empty string. And that something, in this case, is Ruby interpreter. In other words, `"\"\""` dump is *specifically* intended to be eveluated by Ruby interpreter, wheter in `eval`, `instance_eval`, `class_eval`, or `ruby` command line, or `irb`, or what...

Even if there is another way to do it, that way will only end up emulating Ruby interpreter. So I dare to say, no, it does not make too much sense to do it another way.

Answer (score 1):

> ***But besides eval, is there an another way to do it?***

Yes possible,look below using [`YAML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) :

```
require 'yaml'

YAML.load("\"\"") # => ""
YAML.load("\"\"") == "" # => true
```