# What is the opposite of Regexp.escape?

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the opposite of `Regexp.escape` ?

```
> Regexp.escape('A & B')
=> "A\\ &\\ B"
> # do something, to get the next result: (something like Regexp.unescape(A\\ &\\ B))
=> "A & B"
```

How can I get the original value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
replaces = Hash.new { |hash,key| key } # simple trick to return key if there is no value in hash
replaces['t'] = "\t"
replaces['n'] = "\n"
replaces['r'] = "\r"
replaces['f'] = "\f"
replaces['v'] = "\v"

rx = Regexp.escape('A & B')
str = rx.gsub(/\\(.)/){ replaces[$1] }
```

Also make sure to `#puts` output in irb, because `#inspect` escapes characters by default.

Basically escaping/quoting looks for meta-characters, and prepends `\` character (which has to be escaped for string interpretation in source code). But if we find any control character from list: `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, `\f`, `\v`, then quoting outputs `\` character followed by this special character translated to ascii.

*UPDATE*:

My solution had problems with special characters (\n, \t ans so on), I updated it after investigating source code for [rb_reg_quote method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/re.c#L2965).

*UPDATE 2*:

`replaces` is hash, which converts escaped characters (thats why it is used in block attached to `gsub`) to unescaped ones. It is indexed by character without escape character (second character in sequence) and searches for unescaped value. The only defined values are control-characters, but there is also `default_proc` attached (block attached to `Hash.new`), which returns key if there is no value found in hash. So it works like this:

1. for `"n"` it returns `"\n"`, the same for all other escaped control characters, because it is value associated with key
2. for `"("` it returns `"("`, because there is no value associated with `"("` key, hash calls `#default_proc`, which returns key itself

The only characters escaped by `Regexp.escape` are meta characters and control characters, so we don't have to worry about alphanumerics.

Take a look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc for documentation on `#defoult_proc`

Comment: Thanks, But I'm getting double Slash for this: `Regexp.escape('H\B')`

Comment: `puts 'H\B'.inspect` (irb does it to return values) outputs double slash too. Try `puts 'H\B'` and then puts result of my solution's code

Comment: Can you please explain what `replaces[$1]` does?

Comment: @user2503775 See my Update 2 for explanation. Hope it helps understanding this trick

Comment: Thanks. About a single slash - I guess there is no solution.  because `Regexp.escape('H\B')` gives me `"H\\\\B"` so 'I'm getting double Slash for `"H\\\\B".gsub(/\\(.)/){ replaces[$1] }`.. I got `H\\B` for every way that was suggested here. Or maybe you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: @user2503775 Please check http://codepad.org/Ehu1GJQ1. Are you checking results in irb?

Comment: I checked it in rails console and also in irb. And got `=> "H\\B"`: `irb(main):008:0>  Regexp.escape('H\B').gsub(/\\(.)/){ replaces[$1] }`  
`=> "H\\B"`

Comment: @user2503775 You see, double backslash is default when you inspect results in irb (and rails console). Thats why I mentioned you should check results with `puts`. If you output only `"H\B"` in irb/rails console you get the same double backslash - it's not because it is there, but because result string is inspected, and returned with `"` around and backslashes doubled.

Comment: Great! @MBO thank you very much! In the first time you wrote it, I didn't understand you correctly..

Answer (score 1):

using a regex replace using `\\(?=([\\\*\+\?\|\{\[\(\)\^\$\.\#\ ]))\`

should give you the string unescaped, you would only have to replace `\r\n` sequences with there CrLf counterparts.

```
"There\ is\ a\ \?\ after\ the\ \(white\)\ car\.\ \r\n\ it\ should\ be\ http://car\.com\?\r\n"
```

is unescaped to :

```
"There is a ? after the (white) car. \r\n it should be http://car.com?\r\n"
```

and removing the \r\n gives you :

```
There is a ? after the (white) car. 
 it should be http://car.com?
```

Comment: Try it yourself: escaping '\? ?' creates different result than '? \?'

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use something like this?

```
def unescape(s)
  eval %Q{"#{s}"}
end

puts unescape('A\\ &\\ B')
```

Credits to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8639642/1578604).

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/P6sWa8B6)

If you are okay with a regex solution, you can use this:

```
res = s.gsub(/\\(?!\\)|(\\)\\/, "\\1")
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/IgGIN618)

Comment: I always feel unsave when using eval. You can insert evil code when using it: `unescape('"; puts 42#"')` (prints 42, but could possibly execute a script that deletes your SO account)

Comment: @tessi Mhm, I can understand that. I had tried the answers which suggested alternatives but they either used `eval` as well or didn't work. The YAML module seemed to be working for the OP there, but somehow it isn't on codepad; might be the version...

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to use `eval` ... Hoping to find another choice.

Comment: @user2503775 I added a `.gsub` method.

Comment: If you don't already know without any doubt whatsoever that `s` is an escaped regex created entirely under your control, `eval` seems horribly unsafe.  Try `unescape('";print "hi!')`.

Comment: @MBO You're right, and I don't know enough Ruby to put a function in the replace, while I believe yours work correctly :)

Comment: @cHao I guess, yes :( [tessi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1881769/tessi) already mentioned it in an earlier comment, if you can see it.

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah...i see it now.  The example wasn't there when i was posting.  Oh well.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
>> r = Regexp.escape("A & B (and * c [ e] + )")
# => "A\\ &\\ B\\ \\(and\\ \\*\\ c\\ \\[\\ e\\]\\ \\+\\ \\)"
>> r.gsub("\\(","(").gsub("\\)",")").gsub("\\[","[").gsub("\\]","]").gsub("\\{","{").gsub("\\}","}").gsub("\\.",".").gsub("\\?","?").gsub("\\+","+").gsub("\\*","*").gsub("\\ "," ")
# => "A & B (and * c [ e] + )"
```

Basically, these `(, ), [, ], {, }, ., ?, +, *` are the meta characters in regex. And also `\` which is used as an escape character.

The chain of `gsub()` calls replace the escaped patterns with corresponding actual value.

I am sure there is a way to **DRY** this up.

**Update**: *DRY version as suggested by user2503775*

```
>> r.gsub("\\","")
```

**Update**:

following are the special characters in regex

```
    [,],{,},(,),|,-,*,.,\\,?,+,^,$,<space>,#,\t,\f,\v,\n,\r
```

Comment: Would that be true for all types of special characters?

Comment: I cannot say about multi-byte characters. Otherwise, escaping is required only for characters that have special meaning for regex engine. And the characters mentioned above are the only ones I am aware of.

Comment: `r.gsub("\\","")` gives me the same result.. Why do I need the entire line?

Comment: Also... What if I have the character \ in my string?

Comment: Yes. you are right `r.gsub("\\","")` works. That is super DRY. And I guess you can't escape a "\" in a string. `Regexp.escape("\")` returns nothing.

Comment: @Eternal-Learner: `Regexp.escape("\")` would be invalid syntax; the backslash escapes the would-be closing quote, so you never end the string.  Try `Regexp.escape("\\")` instead.

Comment: @Eternal-Learner There is also problem with your gsubs: `"\("` (and other versions too) is just `"("` in Ruby, you need to double backslashes there.