# Automatic replacement of "\n" by "\\n" in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying construct a hash in ruby from the input provided by user.But when i give an string input with "\n",it is automatically replaced by double slash followed by n(\ \n) in the hash.But i want the data to be as it is in the hash.Below is my code.

```
puts "Enter the value" 

value = gets.chomp 

data = { "test" => "data", "value" => value }

puts data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the user end input by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a blank line and leaving the rest of the lines untouched:

```
puts "Enter the value, then hit ENTER on blank line to finish"

value = ''
until (line = gets).chomp.empty?
  value << line
end
value.chomp!

data = { "test" => "data", "value" => value }

puts data
```

This, after entering `foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`bar`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will produce:

```
Enter the value, then hit ENTER on blank line to finish
foo
bar

{"test"=>"data", "value"=>"foo\nbar"}
```

The only limitation is that you cannot have a newline at the end of the value.

---

Another possibility is to “unescape” the string after reading it from the input with `eval`. Since `eval` is potentially insecure, i would rather go with the `yaml` library, as suggested in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639642/whats-the-best-way-to-escape-and-unescape-strings#answer-18752208):

```
require 'yaml'

puts "Enter the value" 

line = gets.chomp
value = YAML.load(%Q(---\n"#{line}"\n))

data = { "test" => "data", "value" => value }

puts data
```

This, after entering `foo\nbar`<kbd>Enter</kbd> will produce:

```
Enter the value
foo\nbar

{"test"=>"data", "value"=>"foo\nbar"}
```

The plus is that this can handle newlines at arbitrary positions.

Comment: Great! Then please consider accepting the answer so it does no longer appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the hash. You simply can't input `\n` as a control character (at least not using `gets`).

If, as a user, you type `\n`, you have typed a literal backslash, followed by a literal `n`. That's represented as `"\\n"` in a string.

The only control character I can think of right now that you *can* input directly is the tab character `\t` (and you get that by typing an actual tab, not `\t`:

```
irb(main):001:0> gets.chomp
\n
=> "\\n"
irb(main):002:0> gets.chomp
a       b
=> "a\tb"
irb(main):003:0> gets.chomp

=> ""
```