# How to convert a backslash hexadecimal string to a binary string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way other than using 'eval'?

```
s = '"\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC\xE8\xAA\x9E"'
puts eval s
```

Comment: You can guard against bad strings with a simple regex, in which case an `eval` is a lot less risky. A very similar regex would give you the  hex codes direct and you could `unpack` them.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22090177/1120015