# nginx logging $request_body as hexadecimal

Tags: json, nginx, hex

I am trying to log the request body of requests to my api and nginx is turning all quotes (and some other characters like spaces and tabs) into hexadecimal characters.

Here is my log format

```
log_format postdata '{"ts": "$time_iso8601", "status": $status, "req": "$uri", "meth": "$request_method", "body": "$request_body"}';
```

Here is what gets logged

```
{"ts": "2015-05-20T15:31:11-07:00", "status": 400, "req": "/v2/track", "meth": "POST", "body": {\x22id\x22:\x22user id\x22}}
```

How can I prevent this so that the resulting log line is

```
{"ts": "2015-05-20T15:31:11-07:00", "status": 400, "req": "/v2/track", "meth": "POST", "body": {"id":"user id"}}
```

Comment: You can't. It's harcoded in nginx's log module. But if you put quotes around (like you show in log format, but not in actual result) it would be valid js string, which you could use in `JSON.parse`

Comment: Well, not actually valid if you use non-ascii, but nginx's log module was written long before JSON became popular or even existed

Comment: Related question which sheds a little insight into this behaviour can be found [here](http://serverfault.com/q/247271)

Comment: Hi @tbeauvais, now there's a real solution to this question - please accept it. See the answer from Grigori Kochanov.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sinse 1.13 there is an "escape=none" parameter that turns off data escaping.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format

```
log_format  api_request_log escape=none '[$time_local] $request \n$request_body';
```

Comment: It's 2020, and this is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: There's also an `escape=json` [as of 1.11.8](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/commit/c40d8dd).

Comment: Is there a reason for using `escape=none` when outputting JSON? Wouldn't `escape=none` mean that JSON metacharacters in request fields (i.e. from network input) could mess with the JSON syntax of the log output?

Answer (score 9):

You can't stop from escaping it and will have to post process it.

Python2 example:

```
line = '{\x22id\x22:\x22user id\x22}'
line.decode('unicode_escape')
>> u'{"id":"user id"}'
```

Python3 example:

```
line = '{\x22id\x22:\x22user id\x22}'
bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
>> '{"id":"user id"}'
```

Ruby example (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752208/2398354):

```
require 'yaml'
line = '{\x22id\x22:\x22user id\x22}'
YAML.load(%Q(---\n"#{line}"\n))
=> "{\"id\":\"user id\"}"
```

Note: This last example is useful if post processing a file with logstash

Answer (score 9):

Hope this will be helpful for someone.
In order to log entire json request unescaped.
Do add in http block this configuration

```
http {
 log_format postdata escape=json $request_body;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log postdata;
 .....
}
```

Comment: this added an additional string literal to my logs `escape=json{\x22d\x22:\x22d\x22}`

Comment: i got it. only nginx <= 1.11.8 supports this

Comment: @JaysonCheng **>=** 1.11.8, right?

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, there is no way to fix this within nginx configuration.
But it is not difficult to post-process it. If the request body is JSON-formatted, you'll probably run into a lot of \x0A (newline) and \x22 (").

Just clear those out with `sed` before looking into the logfile.

Here is the command for you: `LANG='' sed -E 's/(\\x0A|\\x22)//g' access.log`