# Ruby on Rails 4 on Heroku, Environment variables with backslash escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I have an environment variable along the lines of:

```
MY_VALUE: "EFINbA\u003d\u003d\n"
```

When I read it through ruby it is returned as:

```
ENV['MY_VALUE']
=> "EFINbA\\u003d\\u003d\\n"
```

... but only on Heroku, not on Mac (where it was set through a local_env.yml file, admittedly)

So first of all, I just don't understand why it is doing that.

Secondly, when I attempt to remove the \ and replace them with \, I have found nothing that works.

Although:
    ENV['MY_VALUE'].gsub("\","x")
    => "EFINbAxu003dxu003dxn"

This:
    ENV['MY_VALUE'].gsub("\","\")

... doesn't work because the last double-quote is escaped, while:

```
ENV['MY_VALUE'].gsub("\\","\\")
```

... effectively does nothing at all.

Evidently I am missing something basic here, and it's too late in the day for me to spot it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try YAML's unescape

```
require 'yaml'

def unescape(s)
    YAML.load(%Q(---\n"#{s}"\n))
end

unescape(ENV['MY_VALUE'])
```

or if you don't bring in the yaml module you can use `eval`

```
def unescape(s)
    eval %Q{"#{s}"}
end
```

The advantage to `YAML` over `eval` is that it is presumably safer.

Comment: You, sir, have saved my evening. I went with the eval in the end as the process is safe from dodgy inputs. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YAML.safe_load sometimes changes characters in the env string - so it is not an optimal solution.

As eval is also not the solution as it is not that safe, `.undump` was [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343273/12839228) I was looking for.