# How to prevent escaping of an ENV variable passed into ruby application in docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, environment-variables

keys.env contains private key:

```
KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nBADANBgkqhki......xjiWsX7Qjoh8XH8nAECgYEAkCNIy1eICdUUt6HgV\nnEGKpwDETJTIJdmW5MlOzsURI/RSnE2Qas/k758isGLaA4m9dZJoxuP/pCfwcvLj\nwmjVBPdTTNF6ADgor6ZVIp6os5wIIurZH7f8yXaggTEyk5r8K6qxz9t/D\n4FaPDsZ2icg0N5i2y/2Sa0w=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

(The value of KEY should be enclosed in quotes because it contains \n)

*docker-compose.yml* contains *env_file* parameter:

```
version: '2'

services:
  testenv:
    image: ruby:2.4-slim  
    env_file:
      - ./keys.env
```

I run the container with ruby app:

```
docker-compose run testenv
```

and try to use ENV['KEY'] variable:

```
irb(main):001:0> ENV['KEY']
=> "\"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nBADANBgkqhki......xjiWsX7Qjoh8XH8nAECgYEAkCNIy1eICdUUt6HgV\\nnEGKpwDETJTIJdmW5MlOzsURI/RSnE2Qas/k758isGLaA4m9dZJoxuP/pCfwcvLj\\nwmjVBPdTTNF6ADgor6ZVIp6os5wIIurZH7f8yXaggTEyk5r8K6qxz9t/D\\n4FaPDsZ2icg0N5i2y/2Sa0w=\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\""
```

The variable is escaped, but I need clean private_key.

I have not found the answer in the Docker documentations.

I see two working solutions, but none seems to me right.

1. Store private_key in the .env file encoded and without quotes. A
   module in the app will decode this value.
2. Unescape value in the app (like this
   [Best way to escape and unescape strings in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639642/best-way-to-escape-and-unescape-strings-in-ruby))

Is there a way to solve this problem with built-in capabilities of Docker?

Answer (score 2):

You've hit a known issue of docker:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11443

> Sorry for the inconvenience but I would rather go the conservative route on this one :(
>   The problem can be solved with echo -e like you mentioned and I think the benefit of keeping env-file simple is higher.
>   I'm going to close this issue, but feel free to continue the discussion and speak up if you disagree.

The equivalent in ruby of that `echo -e` is replacing literal '\n' with a real newline:

```
ENV['KEY'].gsub('\n', "\n")
```

**And** remove the double quotes, leave it as this:

```
KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nBADANBgkqhki......xjiWsX7Qjoh8XH8nAECgYEAkCNIy1eICdUUt6HgV\nnEGKpwDETJTIJdmW5MlOzsURI/RSnE2Qas/k758isGLaA4m9dZJoxuP/pCfwcvLj\nwmjVBPdTTNF6ADgor6ZVIp6os5wIIurZH7f8yXaggTEyk5r8K6qxz9t/D\n4FaPDsZ2icg0N5i2y/2Sa0w=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

**But** I recommend to just mount a file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  testenv:
    image: ruby:2.4-slim  
    volumes:
      - ./keys.pem:/root/keys.pem
```

Then do a simple file read from ruby.

Comment: thanks. Really, the value of KEY should not be enclosed in quotes

Comment: That's correct. See your own example: `=> "\"---`, see the `\"`