# json.loads with escape characters

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, unicode-escapes

I'm trying to convert this string into python dict:

```
q = '{"request_body": "{\\x22username\\x22:\\x222\\x22,\\x22password\\x22:\\x226\\x22,\\x22id\\x22:\\x22e2cad174-736e-3041-cf7e\\x22, \\x22FName\\x22:\\x22HS\\x22}", "request_method": "POST"}'
```

when I do `json.loads(a)` it giving me an error `simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 19 (char 19)` . So than I decided to convert `\x22` into  `"`. I followed suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219398/how-to-convert-characters-like-x22-into-string) question.

```
>>> q.decode('string_escape')
'{"request_body": "{"username":"2","password":"6","id":"e2cad174-736e-3041-cf7e", "FName":"HS"}", "request_method": "POST"}'
>>>
```

But after that `"{"` part is invalid.
So my question is what are the possible ways to convert string `q` into a python dict?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that JSON doesn't support the `\xNN` escape, only `\uNNNN`. Replacing `\x22` with `"` will make the JSON invalid. What you should do is to replace `\xNN` with `\u00NN`:

```
>>> q = q.replace('\\x', '\\u00')
>>> json.loads(q)
{'request_body': '{"username":"2","password":"6","id":"e2cad174-736e-3041-cf7e", "FName":"HS"}', 'request_method': 'POST'}
```

(Note: This is not a complete solution as it will erratically replace correctly-escaped strings like `abc\\xyz` to `abc\\u00yz`. A complete solution probably needs a regex or even a lexer.)