# Regex for capturing the nth occurrence of a char

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to capture the third comma in strings like:

```
98,52,"110,18479456000019"
```

I thought of something like a character except:

```
[^"0123456789]
```

But, result was the capture of all commas.

After that, I've tried some regex about nth capture - seems to be a solution -, but none works.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to capture the third <kbd>,</kbd>. [This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/lV8bEG/1/) is one way to do so:

```
([\d,])\x22\d+(,)\d+\x22
```

where your desired <kbd>,</kbd> is in the second group <kbd>(,)</kbd>, just to be simple, and you can call it using <kbd>$2</kbd>.

I have added additional boundaries to this RegEx for safety, which you can remove it:

[image]

[<kbd>\x22</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219398/how-to-convert-characters-like-x22-into-string) is just <kbd>"</kbd>, which you can replace, if you wish:

```
([\d,])"\d+(,)\d+"
```

You can also use (<kbd>\</kbd>) and escape a char, where necessary.

---

If your input would be a bit more complex, maybe such as this:

[image]

you might create a middle boundary before the third <kbd>,</kbd> and add all possible chars in the middle boundary (`[\d\w\"]+`), such as [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/qD0252/1/):

```
 (\d+,){2}[\d\w\"]+(,)
```

and capture the third <kbd>,</kbd> using <kbd>$2</kbd>. This time you can also relax your expression from the right side, and it would still work.

You might also add a start <kbd>^</kbd> in the regex:

```
^(\d+,){2}[\d\w\"]+(,)
```

as an additional left boundary which means your input must start with this expression.