# read escaped character \t as '\t' instead of '\\t' Python ConfigParser

Tags: python, escaping, special-characters, configparser

I have a config.ini file containing `delimiter = \t` which i now want to read using the python3 ConfigParser.
However, the resulting string is `'\\t'` instead of `'\t'` which breaks my program.
Is there a more elegant option to solve this problem instead of just manually stripping the extra '\' from every variable containing an escaped character?
I cannot find an option for ConfigParser().read() to not escape the backslash it finds in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 has a 'unicode_escape' codec.

```
r"a\tb".decode('unicode_escape')

'a\tb'
```

Sources:

https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/37952-escape-chars-string

[how do I .decode('string-escape') in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3#14820462)

Comment: Worth noting that `unicode_escape` in Python 3 is for `bytes` only, **not** `str`. You'll have to juggle a bit converting back and forth to use it.

Comment: i want to point people to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885181) for more discussion on this. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69772725) in particular seems to be the most flexible overall