# Reversing Python's re.escape

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, escaping

How to reverse re.escape? [This blog from 2007](https://mentaljetsam.wordpress.com/2007/04/13/unescape-a-python-escaped-string/) says there is no reverse function, but is that still true, ten years later?

Python 2's `decode('string_escape')` doesn't work on all escaped chars (such as space).

```
>>> re.escape(' ')
'\\ '
>>> re.escape(' ').decode('string-escape')
'\\ '
```

Python 3: [Some suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3) `unicode_escape` or `codec.escape_decode` or `ast.literal_eval` but no luck with spaces.

```
>>> re.escape(b' ')
b'\\ '
>>> re.escape(b' ').decode('unicode_escape')
'\\ '
>>> codecs.escape_decode(re.escape(b' '))
(b'\\ ', 2)
>>> ast.literal_eval(re.escape(b' '))
ValueError: malformed node or string: b'\\ '
```

So is this really the only thing that works?

```
>>> re.sub(r'\\(.)', r'\1', re.escape(' '))
' '
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not just keep a copy of the original string?

Comment: I'm importing escaped strings from elsewhere...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So is this really the only thing that works?
>
> ```
> >>> re.sub(r'\\(.)', r'\1', re.escape(' '))
> ' '
> ```

**Yes.** The [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/re.py) for the `re` module contains no `unescape()` function, so you're definitely going to have to write one yourself.

Furthermore, the [`re.escape()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/re.py#L252) function uses [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) …

```
def escape(pattern):
    """
    Escape special characters in a string.
    """
    if isinstance(pattern, str):
        return pattern.translate(_special_chars_map)
    else:
        pattern = str(pattern, 'latin1')
        return pattern.translate(_special_chars_map).encode('latin1')
```

… which, while it can transform a single character into multiple characters (e.g. `[` → `\[`), cannot perform the reverse of that operation.

Since there's no direct reversal of `escape()` available via `str.translate()`, a custom `unescape()` function using `re.sub()`, as described in your question, is the most straightforward solution.