# Convert `\195\164` to `u'\xc4'` - result from DNS resolver back to unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Doing a DNS resolve on a unicode-hostname return the following:

```
'\195\164\195\182\195\188o.mydomain104.local.'
```

The `\195\164` is actually the following unicode letter: `Ä` (`u'\xc4'`).

The original hostname is:

```
ÄÖÜO.mydomain104.local
```

I'm looking for a way to convert it back to the unicode string (in python2.7)

In case the original code is needed, it's something like the following:

```
from dns import resolver, reversename
from dns.exception import DNSException

def get_name(ip_address):
    answer = None
    res = resolver.Resolver()
    addr = reversename.from_address(ip_address)
    try:
        answer = res.query(addr, "PTR")[0].to_text().decode("utf-8")
    except DNSException:
        pass
    return answer
```

> I was looking at both `.encode` and `.decode`, the `unicodedata` lib and `codecs` and found nothing that worked.

Comment: That's not a valid DNS name, international letters in DNS have to be encoded in punycode (`xn--...`). So how did you retrieve this data?

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for the reply, added the python code used there...

Comment: Please post `repr(get_name(ip_address))` so we know exactly what `str` we are dealing with.

Answer (score 4):

Clue #1:

```
In [1]: print(b'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'.decode('utf_8'))
äöü 

In [2]: print(bytearray([195,164,195,182,195,188]).decode('utf-8'))
'äöü'
```

---

Clue #2: Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=string%20literal#string-literals), Python interprets `\ooo` as the ASCII character with octal value `ooo`, and `\xhh` as the ASCII character with hex value `hh`.

Since 9 is not a valid octal number, `'\195'` is interpreted as `'\1'` and `'95'`.

`hex(195)` is `'0xc3'`. So instead of `'\195'` we want `'\xc3'`.
We need to convert decimals after each backslash into the form `\xhh`.

---

In Python2:

```
import re

given = r'\195\164\195\182\195\188o.mydomain104.local.'
# print(list(given))
decimals_to_hex = re.sub(r'\\(\d+)', lambda match: '\\x{:x}'.format(int(match.group(1))), given)
# print(list(decimals_to_hex))
result = decimals_to_hex.decode('string_escape')
print(result)
```

prints

```
äöüo.mydomain104.local.
```

---

In Python3, use [`codecs.escape_decode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151714/190597) instead of `decode('string_escape')`:

```
import re
import codecs

given = rb'\195\164\195\182\195\188o.mydomain104.local.'

decimals_to_hex = re.sub(rb'\\(\d+)',
    lambda match: ('\\x{:x}'.format(int(match.group(1)))).encode('ascii'), given)
print(codecs.escape_decode(decimals_to_hex)[0].decode('utf-8'))
```

prints the same result.