# Removing backslash escape character when saving DataFrame to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I currently have a Pandas DataFrame that contains many backslashes used in escape characters. For example, there are strings that are of the form `'Michael\'s dog'`.

When I save this DataFrame to a CSV file using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`, I would like to get rid of these backslashes so that the entry in the CSV file would simply be `"Michael's dog"`.

Is there a simply way that I can do this, either by taking advantage of a function or method? I've attempted to go through the original DataFrame and make the changes manually but I can't shake off the feeling that there must be a more efficient way.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Sorry for the confusion, perhaps I should have been more specific in my original question.

The data that I'm having trouble with is of the form:

```
[' [\'Mazda\', \'it\', "Mazda \'s", \'its\', \'its\', "Mazda \'s"]',
 " ['the 2019 Mazda3', 'the 2019 Mazda3', 'it', 'the 2019 Mazda3', 'The 2019 Mazda3', 'its']",
 " ['the car', 'its']",
 ' [\'the Japanese automaker\', "the brand \'s"]']
```

As you can see, the data is technically a list and not a string, which means that simply using `replace` won't work.

Comment: don't use str.replace, it will also replace actual data with '\' character... instead use https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820462/6741053

Comment: @Suparshva I don't `replace` will create any problem in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the data, I added tests for your data in my answer.

Comment: The requirements aren't specific enough: should anything else be modified, besides changing a sequence of `\'` into `'`? Also, the data shown is just a list of strings - neither CSV file content nor a Dataframe, so it's hard to relate to the question being asked - and the strings in that list **do not actually have backslashes in them** (that's just something Python is inserting while showing a **representation of** the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use str.replace, it will simply replace every '\' character.

**Use this instead:**

```
df.ColumnName.str.decode('unicode_escape')
```

**Tests:**

```
>>> data = {'Name':['Tom\\\\\'', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.Name.str.decode('unicode_escape')
0    Tom\'
1     nick
2    krish
3     jack
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

**Author's Tests:**

```
>>> data
{'Name': [' [\'Mazda\', \'it\', "Mazda \'s", \'its\', \'its\', "Mazda \'s"]', " ['the 2019 Mazda3', 'the 2019 Mazda3', 'it', 'the 2019 Mazda3', 'The 2019 Mazda3', 'its']", " ['the car', 'its']", ' [\'the Japanese automaker\', "the brand \'s"]']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.Name.str.decode('unicode_escape')
0     ['Mazda', 'it', "Mazda 's", 'its', 'its', "Ma...
1     ['the 2019 Mazda3', 'the 2019 Mazda3', 'it', ...
2                                   ['the car', 'its']
3           ['the Japanese automaker', "the brand 's"]
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

**Source:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820462/6741053