# Why Oracle doesn't escape double backslashes to single?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, dbeaver

I pass the SQL query from a python server to Oracle with double backslashes:

```
SELECT
   ID
FROM
   Works
WHERE
   NAME IN ('ABC\\ABC', 'sdf\\sdfsdf', 'lkj\\sdfsdf')
```

I got nothing after the query was executed. But when remove one backslash and execute in DBeaver (SQL Tool), result is OK.

`NAME` fields in the table have one backslash and look like this: `ABC\ABC`.

Comment: `'ABC\\ABC'` - this is the literal value, period. Oracle will not do anything with it. You need to prepare your value **before** sending it to oracle. phyton has `[string].replace("\\", "\")`. use it.

Comment: See [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).

Comment: @T.S. python always stores double backslashes in a variable to escape it when print, etc. So `replace` and encode/decode don't work in this situation.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for my problem:

1. Bind values in a SQL query in Python:

   https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause;

   Thanks to [Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones) for this solution of binding the values in the `execute` command. It works well with double backslashes.

   ```
    cursor.execute("""
        select employee_id, first_name, last_name
        from employees
        where last_name in (:name1, :name2)""",
        name1="Smith", name2="Taylor")
   ```
2. Play with decode/encode: [how do I .decode('string-escape') in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3).

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is not a special character inside an Oracle string literal, therefore, you do not need to escape it with another backslash.

One thing you do need to escape is the single quote mark by doubling it up (assuming you're not using the "q" syntax), so you'd have a string like `'Susan''s'`