# Use string as bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, character-encoding

My problem is as follows:

I'm reading a .csv generated by some software and to read it I'm using Pandas. Pandas read the .csv properly but one of the columns stores bytes sequences representing vectors and Pandas stores them as a string.

So I have *data* (string) and I want to use np.frombuffer() to get the proper vector. The problem is, *data* is a string so its already encoded so when I use .encode() to turn it into bytes, the sequence is not the original one.

Example: The .csv contains *\x00\x00* representing the vector [0,0] with dtype=np.uint8. Pandas stores it as a string and when I try to process it something like this happens:

```
data = df.data[x] # With x any row.
type(data)
```

<class 'str'>

```
print(data)
```

\x00\x00

```
e_data = data.encode("latin1")
print(e_data)
```

b'\\x00\\x00'

```
v = np.frombuffer(e_data, np.uint8)
print(v)
```

array([ 92 120  48  48  92 120  48  48], dtype=uint8)

I just want to get b'\x00\x00' from data instead of b'\\x00\\x00' which I understand is a little encoding mess I have not been able to fix yet.

Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: CSV is fundamentally a text format. If you want to store "bytes" in it then you need to be *very* clear and explicit about the conventions you are using. If you want to represent a byte with value zero, for example, exactly what *characters of text* do you expect the file to contain? (If you want to use Unicode code point 0 for that, you are probably going to have a bad time.) So, to be clear: your .csv file actually contains a literal backslash, lowercase x, and two zeros for each zero byte?

Comment: `r'\x00\x00'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('ascii')` does what you ask but there is probably a more straightforward way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151714/874188 suggests `import codecs; codecs.escape_decode(r'\x00\x00')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue: you (apparently) have a string that contains literal backslash escape sequences, such as:

```
>>> x = r'\x00' # note the use of a raw string literal
>>> x # Python's representation of the string escapes the backslash
'\\x00'
>>> print(x) # but it looks right when printing
\x00
```

From this, you wish to create a corresponding `bytes` object, wherein the backslash-escape sequences are translated into the corresponding byte.

Handling these kinds of escape sequences is done using the `unicode-escape` string encoding. As you may be aware, string encodings convert between `bytes` and `str` objects, specifying the rules for which byte sequences correspond to what Unicode code points.

However, the `unicode-escape` codec assumes that the escape sequences are on the `bytes` side of the equation and that the `str` side will have the corresponding Unicode characters:

```
>>> rb'\x00'.decode('unicode-escape') # create a string with a NUL char
'\x00'
```

Applying `.encode` to the string will reverse that process; so if you start with the backslash-escape sequence, it will re-escape the backslash:

```
>>> r'\x00'.encode('unicode-escape') # the result contains two backslashes, represented as four
b'\\\\x00'
>>> list(r'\x00'.encode('unicode-escape')) # let's look at the numeric values of the bytes
[92, 92, 120, 48, 48]
```

As you can see, that is clearly not what we want.

We want to convert from `bytes` to `str` to do the backslash-escaping. But we have a `str` to start, so we need to change that to `bytes`; and we want `bytes` at the end, so we need to change the `str` that we get from the backslash-escaping. In both cases, we need to make each Unicode code point from 0-255 inclusive, correspond to a single byte with the same value.

The encoding we need for *that* task is called `latin-1`, also known as `iso-8859-1`.

For example:

```
>>> r'\x00'.encode('latin-1')
b'\\x00'
```

Thus, we can reason out the overall conversion:

```
>>> r'\x00'.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1')
b'\x00'
```

As desired: our `str` with a literal backslash, lowercase x and two zeros, is converted to a `bytes` object containing a single zero byte.

Alternately: we can request that backslash-escapes are processed while *decoding*, by using `escape_decode` from the `codecs` standard library module. However, this [isn't documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) and isn't really meant to be used that way - it's internal stuff used to implement the `unicode-escape` codec and possibly some other things.

If you want to expose yourself to the risk of that breaking in the future, it looks like:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.escape_decode(r'\x00\x00')
(b'\x00\x00', 8)
```

We get a 2-tuple, with the desired `bytes` and what I assume is the number of Unicode code points that were decoded (i.e. the length of the string). From my testing, it appears that it can only use UTF-8 encoding for the non-backslash sequences (but this could be specific to how Python is configured), and you can't change this; there is no actual parameter to specify the encoding, for a `decode` method. Like I said - not meant for general use.

---

Yes, all of that is as awkward as it seems. The reason you don't get easy support for this kind of thing is that it isn't really how you're intended to design your system. Fundamentally, all data is bytes; text is an abstraction that is encoded by that byte data. Using a single byte (with value 0) to represent four characters of text (the symbols `\`, `x`, `0` and `0`) is not a normal encoding, and not a reversible one (how do I know whether to decode the byte as those four characters, or as a single NUL character?). Instead, you should strongly consider using some other friendly string representation of your data (perhaps a plain hex dump) and a non-text-encoding-related way to parse it. For example:

```
>>> data = '41 42' # a string in a simple hex dump format
>>> bytes.fromhex(data) # support is built-in, and works simply
b'AB'
>>> list(bytes.fromhex(data))
[65, 66]
```