# Getting escape sequences from user-input in python

Tags: python, string, user-input

I'm trying to make a program to write a file from user-input, but for some reason when I use \n in input it doesn't work as a newline, it's considered a string instead.

Code: (at the moment the program just prints the user-input)

`print(input("> "))`

User-input:

`"\nHello\nWorld!\n"`

Expected output:

```
Hello
World!
```

Output:

```
\nHello\nWorld!\n
```

Comment: Escape sequences are only processed in string literals, not in data.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for