# Read file as a string literal in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

I am working with a CType function that requires a byte string that is being read in from a file. If I put the string into the script, it will work, as long as I denote the string as a string literal (i.e. with 'r') and then convert it to a byte string. But if I just read it in as a byte string it does not work. Is there a way to read in a file as a string literal?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = r"\x00hello"
    with open('some_file', 'rb') as f: # some file contains only "\x00hello"
        b = f.read()
    c = b"\x00hello"

    x = CtypeObj.Function(a.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')) # success!
    y = CtypeObj.Function(b)                                  # failure!
    z = CtypeObj.Function(c)                                  # failure!
```

Comment: `rb` flag is used to read as bytes. Use `r` to read as string, and use `encoding=utf-8`. It might fail if a non utf-8 character is found in the file.

Comment: "string literal" means a string written into source code. The "r" makes a string literal also a "raw" string that does not treat the backslash specially. What does `b` look like? Can you print it for us to see?

Comment: `a` starts with a backslash while `c` start with a NUL character. Your API seems to not like that NUL.

Comment: Are you aware that `r"\x00" == "\\x00"`? That might be the problem: you might be misunderstanding how data is represented in a string. In that case, there are existing questions about that, like [Why do backslashes appear twice?](/q/24085680/4518341) If the file literally contains quotation marks and a backslash, you might want to read [How to convert string representation of list to a list](/q/1894269/4518341), but I'd question why you have a file like that in the first place. Maybe it's actually JSON?

Comment: If the goal is to encode the NUL in the file, you may be able to `import codecs` and then do `b = codecs.escape_encode(b)`.

Comment: In the above, `print(ascii(a.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')))` as well as `print(ascii(b))` and `print(ascii(c))`.  Post the results.  This will unambiguously show us the *exact* content of each string.

Answer (score 0):

The line that you point at as a success likely isn't doing what you think it is doing either:

```
a = r"\x00hello"
```

That defines a string of 9 characters, `\`, `x`, etc. Calling `a.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')` takes that string and encodes the characters in the string using utf-8 and returns a `bytes` value of that encoding. (which `CtypeObj.Function()` accepts)

I would assume that you don't really want that `\00` part passed to the function?

Reading from the `'rb'` mode file gets you a `bytes` value as well, but the encoding of the file will be the encoding of that `bytes` value. If you need it to be utf-8 encoding (and the file might not be), then you should instead open the file as `'r'`, read the value as a string, and encode with `b.encode('utf-8')`.

And finally this line:

```
c = b"\x00hello"
```

This just creates a length 6 `bytes` value, with the first byte being the `0` byte, and the rest the values for the 5 letters. However, that's not automatically a utf-8 encoding, and certainly not the same as you had before. Again, it would seem you don't want that `\x00` at the start, since it's very unusual for a string to start with a null character like that.

As indicated in the comments, `r"\x00hello"` and `'hello'` are all string literals, but that's only meaningful in the context of code. In terms of data, you only have strings of characters (`str`) and `bytes` values (sometimes called a string of bytes). A "literal" is a way to write either in code directly:

```
s = 'hello'   # a string literal
b = b'hello'  # a bytes literal for the same text (under most encodings)

s == b.decode()  # True
b == s.encode()  # True
```

If you read a file using mode `'r'`, you get strings. If you use a file using mode `'rb'`, you get bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('./file.txt', 'rb') as f:
        # read `\x00hello` from file, remove trailing newline
        line = f.read().rstrip()
        # decode the unicode escapes, then re-encode
        line = line.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')

    print(line)
    print(b'\x00hello')

    print(line == b'\x00hello')
```

Adapted from advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820462/10549827).

---

```
[~] $ cat file.txt
\x00hello
[~] $ python script.py
b'\x00hello'
b'\x00hello'
True
```

Comment: Please vote or flag to close duplicates as duplicates. The extra context for the problem doesn't make it a different problem - it only defocuses the question.