# String Encoding in Python

Tags: python, json, string, character-encoding

I have strings like these - `Trang chủ` and `Đồ Dùng Nhà Bếp` which have special charaters. When i print them, they are shown as it is. But when I convert it into Json, it changes to `Trang ch\xe1\xbb\xa7`. How can I print them as they are in JSON format also? Thanks in advance.

I tried the suggested answer of  -

```
string.encode('utf-8', "ignore")

string.decode("ascii", "ignore")
```

and got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', 'Trang ch\xe1\xbb\xa7', 8, 9, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

Is there a way around?

The link provided as duplicate is not the question I was asking.

The answer provided does solve my question : 
json.dumps(your_string, ensure_ascii=False)

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Where does the data come from? What's the code that's handling it?

Comment: @deceze - python 2.7.6
The data is coming from a Thai website. I was scraping it for some work.

Comment: @sagar - I tried the suggested answer of  - 
string.encode('utf-8', "ignore")
string.decode("ascii", "ignore") and got this error - UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', 'Trang ch\xe1\xbb\xa7', 8, 9, 'ordinal not in range(128)')

Comment: I recommend looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python

Comment: @Petzku - Thanks. But when I tried 

store = ast.literal_eval(store). Here store is dictionary.
I get an error - ValueError('malformed string',)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
json.dumps(your_string, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This will disable escaping non-ascii characters.